# SpriteKit, Swift 2.0 - Scrollview giving me an error

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift2

So I updated the code with the init() and have used the optional binding as you stated it has stopped giving me the error But now it won't even show up when I run the simulation, what is the cause of this?

Also I need it to show up in a different scene called Menu and was wondering how I do that?

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var scrollView: UIScrollView!


convenience init() {

    self.init()

if let tempVar = (scrollView) {

    print("hello world")

}

else if scrollView != nil {

    print("hello")

  }

}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.

        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = true
        // skView.showsPhysics = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        skView.presentScene(scene)

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 400)

      }

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    self.scrollView!.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.scrollView!.contentSize.height = 0
    self.scrollView!.contentSize.width = 400

}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a scroll view (`Scroller`) as an (implicitly unwrapped) optional. An optional says, there is a value and it equals x, or there is no value at all. You have to use optional binding to access  optional's value in a safely way. In the case of implicitly unwrapped optional variable (scrollView! vs scrollView?), like in your case, there is no need to use optional binding to conditionally unwrap the optional (because it will be unwrapped implicitly when accessed), but you have to take care that variable is not nil at the time you try to use it.

Here, a `Scroller` is probably nil because it seems that you haven't actually created an instance of an `UIScrollView` (or at least that can't be seen in your code).

You need to create an instance of a `UIScrollView` before you access its properties:

```
 Scroller = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
```

Another thing which can be noticed is that you are using `unarchiveFromFile` function to create a scene. This is "an old" way and you have to make sure that you have defined this function in a custom extension on a SKNode (because in Xcode 7 this extension can't be found anymore in default SpriteKit game template project).

Also, when using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` note that it can be called multiple times.

**Hint:** Class names should be capitalized, while variables should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Hi, i am new to coding so could you explain it in a more simple terms? I'm just not that up to speed with all the programming jargon just yet.

Comment: @Astrum In short, you have to make sure that Scroller variable is not nil before you try to access it (or its properties).

Comment: how would i go about checking that? (I only started programming a week ago) and if it is nill how would i go about fixing it?

Comment: @Astrum Use optional binding, if let tempVar = optionalVar{...} Or if optionalVar != nil { //... Use forced unwrapping here } But beside all that, seems that you don't understand that you have to initialize object before you use it. If you are beginner, you have to start with basic OOP concepts, like classes, objects, initialization, variables. Then go to Swift specific stuff like optionals. etc. and after that you can jump in, and use UIKit elements like UIScrollView.

Comment: Hi, can you read my question again because i have updated it with the new code and have a few more questions about it.